# Unable to run a dtsx package through powershell

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, ssis, package

I am trying to run a bunch of stored procedures and in the end run a dtsx package which is already set up in the SQL server through powershell
I get the below as the location of the dtsx while initiating the package from SQL mgmt studio using powershell. However my PS ISE is not talking to this location.

PS SQLSERVER:\SSIS\SM024591\DEFAULT\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\006_EXPORTDATA\Projects\EXPORT-P-USU-MULTI-DSDB\Packages\EXPORT-P-USU-MULTI-DSDB%2Edtsx

I tried to find the real path of PS SQLSERVER:\SSIS\SM024591\DEFAULT\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\006_EXPORTDATA\Projects\EXPORT-P-USU-MULTI-DSDB\Packages\EXPORT-P-USU-MULTI-DSDB%2Edtsx which seems to be in a DB server engine
and it seems like mapping is only for PS instance and only valid once the PS session running

Any guidance would be much appreciated so that I can run the below with the correct path or any other suggestions are welcome too

(Get-ChildItem Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider\SqlServer::SQLSERVER:\SSIS\SM024761\DEFAULT\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\006_EXPORTDATA\projects | WHERE { $_.Name -eq 'EXPORT-P-USU-MULTI-DSDB.dtsx' }).Execute("false", 0)

Comment: Using SSMS check the log files using the explorer under management.  Check for errors at the time you run PS.  Also compare the SSMS login info with the login being used against the PS login.  Make sure the Account/Group are the same in SSMS and PS.

Comment: Extended Events session and select error event.